# Algorithm for merging short lists into a long vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix class whose non-zeros and corresponding column indices are stored, in row-order, in what are basically STL-vector-like containers. They may have unused capacity, like vectors; and to insert/remove elements, existing elements must be moved.

Say I have an operation, `insert_erase_replace`, or `ier` for short. `ier` can do the following, given a position `p`, a column index `j`, and a value `v`:

- if `v==0`, `ier` removes the entry at `p` and left-shifts all subsequent entries.
- if `v!=0`, and `j` is already present at `p`, `ier` replaces the cell contents at `p` with `v`.
- if `v!=0`, and `j` is not present at `p`, `ier` inserts the entry `v` and column index `j` at `p` after right-shifting all subsequent entries.

So all of that is trivial.

Now let's say I have `ier2`, which does the same thing, except that it takes a list containing multiple column indices `j` and corresponding values `v`. It also has a size `n`, which indicates how many index/value pairs are present in the list. But because the vector only stores non-zeros, sometimes the actual insertion size is smaller than `n`.

Still trivial.

But now let's say I have `ier3`, which takes not just one list like `ier2`, but multiple lists. This represents editing a slice of the sparse matrix.

At some point, it becomes more efficient to iterate through the vectors, copying them piece by piece and inserting/replacing/erasing the list indices/values `ier2`-style as we arrive at each insertion point. And if the total insertion size would cause my vector to need a resize anyway, then we do that.

**Given that my vector is much, much larger than the total length of the lists, is there an algorithm for efficiently merging the lists into the vector?**

So far, here's what I have:

- Each list passed to `ier3` represents either a net deletion of entries (a left shift), a net replacement (no movement, therefore cheap), or a net insertion of entries (a right shift). There may also be some re-arrangement of elements in there, but the expensive parts are the net deletions and net insertions.
- It's not hard to figure out an algorithm for efficiently doing ONLY net insertions or net deletions.
- It's harder when either of the two may be happening.

The only thing I can think to do is to handle it in two passes:

1. Erase/replace
2. Insert/replace

We erase first because it makes it more likely that any insertions will require fewer copies.

Is this the right approach? Does anyone know of a better one?

Comment: Is there a reason the sparse matrix class is using a vector rather than a list?  If you had a list, then iterators are still valid after an insertion, which makes the problem much easier.

Comment: It's the "yale" sparse matrix specification. Diagonals are O(1), row beginnings and ends are O(1), and you want to be able to binary search for columns within those rows. I suspect using a list would also mess up some of the mathematical operations.

Comment: It seems to me the input list for ier3 might be comparable in size to the existing matrix elements in those rows - can you just combine all the relevant elements in temporary arrays while removing zeroes, resize the big vector and copy everything in?

Comment: This is the algorithm for *avoiding* a resize operation. That is, when there's enough unused space reserved that the merge can be done in-place. A resize would require copying the whole vector, which we want to avoid due to the size.

Comment: Yes, I mean copying only the affected rows, not the entire vector. Depending on your data sets that could be much faster and guarantees only one modification of anything outside the affected rows. Although when I said resize I should have said shift.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I'm going to suppose the intervals covered in each list in `ier3` are disjoint and given to you in order. If it's meant for editing slices of a matrix, this seems reasonable. I'm also assuming you that you don't need to resize the vector, because that case is easily detectable and solvable.

Initialise a `read` pointer and a `write` pointer to the start of the vector you're editing. There'll be an `instruction` pointer into `ie3` too, but I'll ignore that here for clarity's sake. You'll also need a queue. At each step, one of several things can happen:

- Default: Neither `read` nor `write` are at a position detailed by `ier3`. In this case, add the element under `read` to the back of the queue and write the element at the front of the queue to the cell under `write`. Move both pointers forward one.
- `read` is over a cell that needs to be deleted. In this case, simply move `read` forward one **without** adding anything to the queue.
- `read` passes from one cell to the next such that an insertion should happen between them. In this case, add the insertion to the back of the queue and then continue with the next relevant case.
- `read` is at a cell that needs to be modified. In this case, insert the modified cell at the back of the queue, write whatever's at the front of the queue to `write`, and step them both forwards.
- `read` has arrived at the unused capacity of the vector. In which case just `write` whatever's left in the queue.

That's the basic outline, but a couple of optimizations can be made: first, if the queue's empty, step both pointers forward to the next position detailed by `ie3` without doing anything. Second, minimize the buffer by doing extra writing steps whenever `read` is ahead of `write` and the queue is nonempty.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with your plan with a few important points highlighted.

The erase/replace step should start from the left and only move points within the affected range - it can leave a "gap". It should determine the size of the final vector. At the end of this step, use the determined size to shift the "tail" of the vector as needed, leaving the exact amount of space required for insertions free.

The insertions should start from the right and fill up the gap we left in step 1 by copying each point to it's final position.

This will never shift the main vector once and never copy any point (from the existing slice or insertion set) more than twice so it's essentially linear.

Other data structures might be helpful too - reserving space at both the front and end, or building it out of multiple sections so a resize doesn't force a full copy.

One further optimisation would be to allow some insertions during step 1. If you've erased some, completing any insertion you come across immediately until it balances will prevent you needing to move any points until you reach another erase.

Comment: Having free space at the beginning is an interesting idea. I guess I had heard that's in the STL vector type and then totally forgot about it. That may take a bit of work to implement in this case -- right now, reserve space is exclusively at the end. The main reason for that is that the first `n+1` entries in an `n` by `m` matrix are index locations that never move.

Comment: Depends how much you need the performance then. Is there anything in particular you want from the ier3 algorithm? This one has pretty good worst case complexity whereas I suspect the general algorithm to avoid all unnecessary copies is not linear, if it even exists.

Answer (score 0):

Let `n` be the size of the list and `m` be the size of the vector. It sounds like `ier` does a binary search for `j` every time, so the searching part is `O(n*log(m))`.

Assuming the elements in the list are sorted, once you find the first element, it's faster to just navigate up the vector to find the next one. That way searching becomes `O(log(m) + n) = O(n)`.

Also, do a dry pass first to count net deletions/insertions, and a second pass to actually apply the changes. I think these two passes will run faster than the two you describe.

Comment: This sounds like what I *was* doing. The problem is that some rows need insertions *and* deletions. This algorithm, BTW, works fine when there's a copy operation, but it doesn't work for in-place.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a different design for a sparse matrix that should help you achieve performance and a low memory footprint for large sparse matrices.
Instead of vector, why not use a 2D hash table. something like (no std:: for smaller code):

```
typedef unordered_map< unsigned /* index */, int /* value */ > col_type;
unordered_map< unsigned /* index */, col_type*>; // may need to define hash function for col_type
```

the outer class (sparse_matrix) searches in O(1) for a column. If not found, it allocates a new column.
Then the column type is searched for the column index in O(1) and either delete/replace or insert based on the original logic. It can see if the column is now empty and delete it from the 'row' hash map.

all basic operations add/delete/replace are O(1).
If you need a fast ordered iteration of the matrix, you can replace the unordered_map with 'map'. If the matrix is very sparse, the O(nlog(n)) complexity will be similar to the hash_map's.
BTW I used pointer to the col_type on purse, the outer hash map grows much (much!) faster this way.

Comment: The current structure is utilized because of its compatibility with existing published algorithms.

Comment: Alright then. The queuing proposal made by Andy Jones will work at linear complexity assuming your update lists are sorted. If you provide an optimized start (first list item) stop conditions, the average case will be quick as many times only a partial copy will occur.